# Other paid work not specified as conflict of commitment

Tags: conflict-of-interest

I have worked full time for my employer in the US (research organization, let's call it COMPANY A) since May 2022, roughly 5 months. Starting yesterday, the company is asking all employees to sign a Conflict of Interest, Conflict of Commitment, and Confidentiality Policy document.

I know this is pretty standard with independent research organizations, so I'm okay with a lot of what's written. Here is how they define the various conflicts:

*Conflict of Interest refers to a situation in which staff’s private interests could compete with, or perceived to compete with, official responsibilities for private gain or expectation of private gain, non- monetary or otherwise. A conflict may also occur when staff’s private interest may benefit their family, friends or their
organizations.*

*Conflict of commitment refers a situation in which staff’s allocation of time and effort to external activities, could come impact the performance of their job duties.*

*Confidential information includes but is not limited to staff reports, third party information, personal information, technical, financial or scientific information.*

However, there is a portion where they ask us to answer Yes/No questions relating to these policies, and I have an issue with the wording for #3:

1. Do you have any current outside interest that
   can pose as a conflict of interest or conflict of commitment?

Outside interest refers to activities outside the organization (excluding activities pertaining to normal course of professional duties or research publishing). Remuneration may/may not be received for these activities, but such activities may lead to a conflict between the interests of COMPANY A and those of the individual concerned.

2. Would you use COMPANY A's name and address in any documents for outside interest?
3. **Given a chance to take up private/personal consultancy work or other paid work, while still employed at COMPANY A,
   would you accept the offer?**
4. Will you ever divulge any confidential information (unless required by law or authorized by the organization),
   directly or indirectly, to anyone?

I just got this last night, and I am looking for more information about how I should respond.

My first instinct is to ask them to define what they mean by "other paid work" because this clause seems to include all paid work regardless of a conflict!

This employer is not ethical in my opinion, so anything is possible. The pay and benefits are also not enough to warrant working exclusively for them.

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Hey! Does Company A have an HR department? My first thought would be to ask them for clarification on the terms of this contract. We won't be able to help you on what they meant to say, but IMO it does look poorly worded. If they were malicious, they could indeed try to include _all_ work in there

Answer (score 1):

They are pretty clearly trying to soft-push you into agreeing to offer exclusivity.  That's what this whole "Conflict of commitment" thing *means*.  You assert that they are not ethical, and the pay/benefits are not enough to warrant exclusivity.  Looks like it's time to look for a new job, one way or the other.

In the meantime, your options are...

- Say that you'll give them the exclusivity they ask for.  Tell the truth, and actually give then that exclusivity.
- Say that you'll give them the exclusivity, but lie.  This... is moderately unethical, and I would consider it bad policy.  It's not that they necessarily deserve that degree of loyalty from you or whatever.  It's that there are internal psychological advantages to not maintaining ongoing falsehoods.
- Say that you won't, and deal with the fallout.  This is highly likely to include your workplace becoming more hostile to you and/or you being fired, depending.

Regardless, again, start looking.

If the workplace you are in was a healthy one, you might be able to go to your boss with these sorts of concerns, but based on what you're saying here, it's really not.  They're pulling a power play, you're not happy to give it to them, it's time to go.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and feedback! Ben Barden- yes, I think you are spot on with these options. Flats- there is no official HR, just one or two people who help out with admin tasks. Joe Strazzere - indeed, I will ask for clarification.